# python modifying the elements in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

So I have a python dictionary called "p", where

```
import nltk, json, cPickle, itertools
import numpy as np
p = {key1: nan, key2: 0.1, key3: nan}
```

nan is np.nan.

I want to write a piece of code that if a value in the dictionary is equal to nan, then it is changed to 0 instead. I wrote the following code:

```
for key,value in p:
 if value == np.nan:
  p[key] = 0
```

However, the compiler returns with an error saying "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

I also want to sum up all the values in the dictionary after all the nan's have been converted to 0s, then divide each value by that sum. I wrote

```
normalization_factor = float(sum(p.values()))
for key, value in p:
p[key] = value/normalization_factor
```

Again, the compiler returns the ValueError stated above.

Is there a way to fix the error, or a way to go around this error by doing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, iterating over a dictionary iterates over only the keys.  To iterate over key/value pairs, you need to do `for key, value in p.iteritems()` (or `p.items()` in Python 3).

However, you will then run into problems because `nan` is not equal to itself.  You should do `if value is np.nan` or `if np.isnan(value)`.